# Enlisting the Gtk.Dialog.Close event from another dialog is never triggered (C# mono)

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

I'm enlisting to the Gtk.Dialog close event from another dialog like this:

```
AddTask dialog = new AddTask (task); //AddTask inherits from Gtk.Dialog
dialog.Close += HandleDialogClose;
dialog.Show();

void HandleDialogClose (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refresh(); //Does some stuff in the calling dialog
}
```

When I close the dialog (the one I created above), the HandleDialogClose event is never triggered. Any idea why?

Here is some sample code, and I solved it now myself. I was enlisting to the Close() event,  when I should have been enlisting the Destroyed() event. The code below now works (the commented code is what was not working).

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace test
{
    public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
    {   
        public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
        {
            Build ();
            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Label = "Open About";
            this.Add(button1);
            button1.Show();
            button1.Clicked += HandleButton1Clicked;
        }

        void HandleButton1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            About dialog = new About();
            //dialog.Close += HandleAboutClose;
            dialog.Destroyed += HandleAboutClose;
            dialog.Show();
        }

        protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
        {
            Application.Quit ();
            a.RetVal = true;
        }

        void HandleAboutClose (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("About Closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal program that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use

```
dialog.Destroyed += HandleAboutClose;
```

instead of

```
dialog.Close += HandleAboutClose;
```